# Word that means "[doing something] free from expectation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in, an expectation-free hug with your partner. Doing something without expecting anything in return, but not necessarily selfless. I hoped "nonexpecting" was a word, but it seems reserved for pregnancy

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions! My example may not have been the best. I don't mean necessarily platonic or friendly, because the attitude can apply to anything. I've heard the words "wishless" and "hopeless" in some Buddhist contexts, interestingly, but those seem wonky as well.

Comment: Single word requests should always be accompanied by the sentence in which you intend to use the word (leave a blank for the word).

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you are describing is similar to a [***no strings attached***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+strings+attached) situation.

A term to describe a generous person that doesn't expect anything in return would be ***altruistic***:

> Showing a disinterested and selfless concern for the well-being of others; unselfish.
> *‘it was an entirely **altruistic** act’*
> <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/altruistic)</sub>

As an abuse of language, there is usage to apply the adjective (or synonym, like *unselfish*, or *selfless*) to the thing given rather than the person giving it. It is understood that the usage means the person providing the thing has the quality.

> A blood donation is truly an *altruistic gift* that an individual can give to others in need.
> <sub>[Association for the Advancement of Blood & Biotherapies](https://www.aabb.org/for-donors-patients/why-donate-blood)</sub>

You may also consider ***unconditioned***.

> 1. Not subject to conditions or to an antecedent condition; unconditional.
>    *‘pure and **unconditioned** love’*
>
> <sup>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unconditioned)</sup>

Or perhaps ***free***.

> 5. Given or available without charge.
>    *‘**free** healthcare’*
>
> <sup>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/free)</sup>

Either can be used to express the sentiment that there is no obligation to provide anything in return.

---

However, specifically to the hug example, an appropriate phrase would be a ***friendly*** hug:

<sup>Note that I provided this suggestion before the question was edited to specifically exclude it.</sup>

> 1. : of, relating to, or befitting a friend: such as
>    a. : showing kindly interest and goodwill
>         ***friendly** neighbors*
>
> <sup>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/friendly)</sup>

An example of its usage:

> A ***friendly hug*** is when two people embrace each other briefly and then quickly withdraw from the hug; it only lasts for a short period of time. Also, a friendly hug is often accompanied by a pat on the other person’s back to indicate their platonic relationship.
> <sub>[Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-differentiate-a-friendly-hug-from-a-loving-hug)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

How about unassuming? As in an unassuming (not having or showing a desire to be noticed, praised, etc.) hug.

Comment: Good word! Make sure to include your sources when defining a word, as it makes your answer more reputable and more likely to be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

**insouciant**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/insouciant)

Marked by blithe unconcern; nonchalant.

Answer (score 1):

I’m surprised no one has yet suggested **disinterested**, which would be perfect in some contexts. Beware of confusion with “uninterested,” of course.

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disinterested?s=t), disinterested is an adjective meaning:

> unbiased by personal interest or advantage; not influenced by selfish motives

Example from the same source:

> a disinterested decision by the referee.

Attribution: "Disinterested." Dictionary.com. Accessed March 31, 2018. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disinterested?s=t.

Comment: Please add sources to support your answers.

Comment: From Dictionary.com:adjective
1.
unbiased by personal interest or advantage; not influenced by selfish motives:
a disinterested decision by the referee.

Answer (score 1):

I found my way here looking for "free from expectation" and "no pressure" and settled on **casual**

> casual
>  1. relaxed and unconcerned.
> [Google/Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+casual)

> casual
>  3 a (1) : done without serious intent or commitment
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/casual)

For example:
I am casually providing this for review at your discretion.

or
Here is a good casual read.

Answer (score 0):

- *cursory*[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cursory) literally means it’s something done in passing, superficially, with no deeper meaning intended, likely taking little time.
- *innocuous*[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/innocuous) is obviously related to *innocent* and literally means ‘harmless’ or ‘not hurting’, especially in a sense that something is not intended to inflict harm whether it does or not.
- *complimentary[3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complimentary)* (not *complementary*) means something is done out of politeness because it is the proper, civil thing to do, i.e. complying to those social customs. *courteous*[3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complimentary) or *by courtesy* aims for a higher, more noble standard.
- *unconditional*[4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unconditional) and *termless*[5](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/termless) are probably closest to the meaning of ‘not expecting anything in return’, but they seem too strong.
- *without any ulterior[6](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ulterior) motives* is descriptive but not a single word.

Answer (score 0):

> Word that means “free from expectation"?

I would use [detached](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/detached): (dɪtætʃt  )
1. *adjective*
Someone who is detached is not personally involved in something or has no emotional interest in it.

...Or **detachment**, for the *noun* form.

*Can the Practice of Buddhist [Detachment](https://www.healthcentral.com/article/can-the-practice-of-buddhist-detachment-make-you-feel-happier) Make you Feel Happier?*

Answer (score 0):

gratis

> adjective Given or done for nothing; free.
>  ‘gratis books’
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gratis)

Can be used as adjective or adverb. I'd point out that "gratuitous" can have the same meaning, however notice it is definition number 2, meaning its more common use is slightly different:

> adjective
>   1.Done without good reason; uncalled for.
>  ‘gratuitous violence’
>
> 2.Given or done free of charge.
>  ‘solicitors provide a form of gratuitous legal advice’
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gratuitous)

I'd note also that "gratis" or "gratuitous" in the second sense, as far as I know, might be interchangeable with "free".

Answer (score 0):

The term "supererogatory" seems to capture part of what you are trying to say. It refers to morally good acts that are highly recommended but not strictly required. Donating blood to charity or forgiving a stranger for his remarks are examples of such acts.

Less technically, we may say "beyond duty" or in Scottish "outwith duty".

Still more colloquially, we may say "nice" as opposed to "kind" to behaviors that go beyond what is due. For example, we may call someone "nice" or "awfully nice" for holding the door for every stranger that comes after him. And we may call someone "kind" for holding the door only for people in wheelchair.

Comment: *Supererogatory* seems to be in a register way above the little context we have.